# Pagination on large data sets? – Abort count(*) after a certain time

Tags: oracle10g, pagination, performance

We use the following pagination technique here:

- get `count(*)` of given filter
- get first 25 records of given filter

-> render some pagination links on the page

This works pretty well as long as `count(*)` is reasonable fast. In our case the data size has grown to a point where a non-indexd query (although most stuff is covered by indices) takes more than a minute. So at this point the user waits for a mostly unimportant number (total records matching filter, number of pages). The first N records are often ready pretty fast.

Therefore I have two questions:

- can I limit the `count(*)` to a certain number
- or would it be possible to limit it by time? (no `count()` known after 20ms)

Or just in general: are there some easy ways to avoid that problem? We would like to keep the system as untouched as possible.

Database: Oracle 10g

**Update**

There are several scenarios

- a) there's an index -> neither `count(*)` nor the actual select should be a problem
- b) there's no index

  - `count(*)` is HUGE, and it takes ages to determine it -> rownum would help
  - `count(*)` is zero or very low, here a time limit would help. Or I could just dont do a `count(*)` if the result set is already below the page limit.

Comment: An index can only be used to satisfy a COUNT(*) query if it's against one or more NOT NULL columns.  And if the user only cares about the first N records, say records 1-25 of at least 25 - they'll only get the final count when they've hit the last record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 'where rownum < x' to limit the number of rows to count. And if you need to show to your user that you has more register, you could use x+1 in count just to see if there is more than x registers.

Comment: Ah very nice. Didn't realize that I can use rownum with count(*).

Comment: there's also a strange trick to limit to running time, but it sounds extremely hacky.